# How to detect the current report in settings.twig

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutreports

I have several reports to create but their settings are going to be very similar.  So I want to use one settings.twig for all of them and detect which report is the current one to show any extra settings.

Something like this pseudo code:

```html
<div><!--common field--></div>
<div><!--common field--></div>
<div><!--common field--></div>
{% set current_report = craft.barrelstrength.sproutreports.current %}
{% if current_report == 'fourth_quarter_payments' %}
  <div><!--some field--></div>
{% elseif current_report == 'payments_above_100' %}
  <div><!--some field--></div>
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible to know what the current report is so conditionals can be used in the settings template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this post, the only variable available to the settings template that might help you out is the settings object: `{{ dump(settings) }}`.

As this is the Twig Template report, you might be able to use the `settings.resultsTemplate` value to identify the active report in a shared settings file.

---

I've [opened a ticket](https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-reports/issues/108) for adding improved support for this scenario and will look into making the `dataSource` object available to the settings template in a coming release.

Comment: `settings.resultsTemplate` is what I was looking for.  Thanks!